# How come I can't give my pygame window a name or an icon?

Tags: python, pygame, icons

A screenshot of me running my code is below

[image: picture]

and here is my actual code:

```
import pygame


pygame.init()
```

#create the screen

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

## Title and Icon

```
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo-flying.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

running = True
while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    running = False
```

I don't understand why it's not working. My code looks right, my icons in my directory, but nothing is coming up. Is it something I forgot to download? Is my code wrong?

This is the tutorial I'm following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_HF852IONl8

One last thing that might be important to know is that even when I run my window without trying to change the title and icon, it's blank. This leads me to believe that there's a package I still haven't downloaded but I really don't know.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You might want to edit the question because the screenshot was not included.

Comment: I'm curious what operating system and pygame version you are using. Try setting the icon before set_mode, the docs suggest that may be necessary.

Comment: Hmm. It didn't seem to work.

Comment: My operating system is Pycharm for linux. I updated my pygame but I don't know what version it is.

Comment: @OliverRovers it sounds like a problem between Wayland and pygame. It's the new linux display standard that lots of things are adopting. So if you have an up to date distribution  this might be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First of all change the pixel size of this image 'ufo-flying.png' to 32 x 32. To do this open this image with any photo editor app on pc. Choose the "resize" option. Now change the width and height to 32 x 32. You may use this site to change the pixels of this image. https://www.reduceimages.com/ Now save this image to the folder which contains this python code file(main.py). If you are using Pycharm then you can find this folder in the "PycharmProjects" folder on your pc. After doing this, run your code and it will work fine. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

See [`pygame.display.set_icon()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_icon):

> [...] Some systems do not allow the window icon to change after it has been shown. This function can be called before `pygame.display.set_mode()` to create the icon before the display mode is set.

Set the icon before `screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))`:

```py
icon = pygame.image.load('ufo-flying.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
```

In addition, the size of the icon is limited:

> [...] You can pass any surface, but most systems want a smaller image around 32x32.

If the icon is not displayed, try a smaller icon.